# How do I register only internal NIC address in AD DNS, with servers with multiple NICs?

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, cloud, rackspace

I'm hosting some Windows servers on Rackspace, and have added them to a domain. Each server has two NICs, a `public` and `private` NIC. The `public` NIC has a public IPv4 and IPv6 address, while the `private` NIC has an RFC1918 address for communicating with other VMs within the datacenter.

The AD DNS has registered `A` and `AAAA` records for each IP address, for each client. Therefore, `CLIENT01` looking up the IP address for `CLIENT02` first gets the `AAAA` record, and then the public `A` record, then the private `A` record.

I know for my purposes, I only want the clients communicating with each other on the private network, because public bandwidth is billable. Also, the firewalls on each device behave differently for each NIC.

Is there an easy way of specifying (as a matter of policy?) that only a specific NIC should register its address in the AD DNS, so that client name resolution for other clients only returns a private address?

Answer (score 8):

In the Advanced TCP/IP settings for the IPv4 and IPv6 configuration of the external adapters, uncheck `Register this connection's address in DNS` in the DNS tab.

[image]

Comment: Can I automate this with GPO? Or is this a 'log onto each box and uncheck a box/run a script' type thing?

Comment: You can probably automate it with a `netsh` script, but I don't think there are any point-and-click GPOs for this. I could be wrong, though.

Comment: Ok, I'll see if I can powershell it, or something. Thanks.